# Getting "unknown ReadRequestTimeout parameter"

Tags: apache

I've configured an `apache 2.4.6` webserver, and am hardening it with the `RequestReadTimeout` directive. All the parameters such as `header`, `MinRate`, and `body` are accepted, but when I add `handshake=20`, then `apachectl` throws me an error `handshake=20: Unknown RequestReadTimeout paramater`. According to the apache.org doc, the handshake parameter is available in versions 2.2 and later. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Why 2.4.6? You can use 2.4.46. It has more security fixes. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handshake stage is not available until 2.4.39. If you omit setting that variable, the httpd service will run as expected. Please see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html.